# Problem with changing variables of objects

Tags: java, processing

my problem is that when one ball object collides with the left, right or top of the screen, or collided with either of the bricks it will invert the velocity of all the balls for example if ball 1 hits the left wall it will bounce off in the opposite X direction. However, ball 2 will also do the same even when it doesn't collide with anything (the same thing happens to ball 1 when ball 2 hits something).

I am using the Processing development environment. however, this uses Java, specifically the PApplet class

This is my method to move the balls:

```
void moveBalls(){
PVector ballPos;
for(balls b : ballsCollection){
  ballPos = b.getPos();
  if(b.isMoving()) {
    //make the ball bounce off the walls  
    if(ballPos.y > height - blockSize){ //bottom
      if(ballsInMotion == ballsCollection.size()){
         ballPos.y = height - ballSize/2 - blockSize - 3;
         ballStartX = ballPos.x;
         ballStartY = height - blockSize - ballSize - ballSize/2;
         b.invertMoving();
         ballsInMotion -=1;
         println("FirstBall down" + ballPos);
      } else {
         b.invertMoving();
         ballsInMotion -=1;
         PVector p = new PVector(ballStartX,ballStartY);
         b.setPos(p);
         println("Next ball Down new P: " + p);
      }
      if(ballsInMotion == 0){
         setUpNextRound = true; 
      }
    }
    if (ballPos.y < ballSize + blockSize){ //top
       b.invertV("y");
       ballPos.y = ballSize+blockSize;
       println("ball " + b.getIndex() + " hit Top");
    }
    if (ballPos.x > width - ballSize/2){ //right
       b.invertV("x"); 
       ballPos.x = 2*width-ballSize-ballPos.x;
       println("ball " + b.getIndex() + " hit right");
    }
    if (ballPos.x < ballSize/2){ //left
       b.invertV("x"); 
      ballPos.x = ballSize-ballPos.x;
      println("ball " + b.getIndex() + " hit left");
    }

    for(blocks block : blocksCollection){
      int blockHealth = block.getBlockHealth();
      int blockX = block.getX();
      int blockY = block.getY();
      boolean hit = false;
       if(blockHealth > 0){
                 //     Bottom of the block                                                                                                                            Top of the Block       
         if(!hit && (blockBallCollision(blockX+blockSize/2, blockY+blockSize, blockSize-blockCournerSize, 0, ballPos.x-b.getV().x, ballPos.y-b.getV().y, 2*(ballSize)) || blockBallCollision(blockX+blockSize/2, blockY, blockSize-blockCournerSize, 0, ballPos.x-b.getV().x, ballPos.y-b.getV().y, 2*(ballSize)))) {

                println("Block Collision Top/Bottom: " + block.getIndex() + " by Ball: " + b.getIndex());

                b.invertV("y");
                block.blockHit();
                hit = true;
                 //     Left of the block                                                                                                  Right of the Block 
           } else if ( !hit && (blockBallCollision(blockX, blockY+blockSize/2, 0, blockSize-blockCournerSize, ballPos.x-b.getV().x, ballPos.y-b.getV().y, 2*(ballSize)) || blockBallCollision(blockX+blockSize, blockY+blockSize/2, 0, blockSize-blockCournerSize, ballPos.x-b.getV().x, ballPos.y-b.getV().y, 2*(ballSize)))){

               println("Block Collision Left/Right: " + block.getIndex() + " by Ball: " + b.getIndex());
               b.invertV("x");
               block.blockHit();
               hit = true;
           }
      }
    }
      b.movePosV();
      drawBalls();
    }

}
```

}

The ball object is stored:

```
    public class balls{
  private int index;
  private PVector b = new PVector();
  private PVector bV = new PVector();
  private boolean moving, needMoving;

  public balls(int Index, float X, float Y, boolean m, PVector ballV){
      index = Index;
      b.x = X;
      b.y = Y;
      moving = m;
      bV = ballV;
  }
  public void movePosV(){
     b.sub(bV); 
  }
  public void invertV(String xy){
      if(xy.equals("x")){
        bV.x = -bV.x;
      } else {
        bV.y = -bV.y;
      }
  }
  public void setPos(PVector newB){
    b = newB;  
  }
  public void setV(PVector newV){
     bV = newV; 
  }
  public boolean getNeedMoving(){
     return needMoving; 
  }
  public PVector getV(){
     return bV; 
  }
  public PVector getPos(){
     return b; 
  }
  public int getIndex(){
      return index;   
  }
  public boolean isMoving(){
      return moving;
  }
  public void invertMoving(){
      moving = !moving;
  }
  public void invertNeedMoving(){
      needMoving = !needMoving;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code is referencing so many class members in your method that we don’t know how they’re set or updated so it’s very hard to understand why your code isn’t working. I suggest you use the debugger to to try to figure out what’s going on. Also a friendly advice, let class names start with a capital character and be in singular not plural. So let `balls` be `Ball` instead, this will make it easier for others to read your code. And boolean variables or parameter names should start with “is”, like `isMoving`.

Comment: awesome thank you very much, that was a good help I cleaned up my code and found where the problem was.